# Is it possible to show the value of foreignkey in modelformset and not id

Tags: django, django-forms, formsets

I have 2 models as below :

```
class Types_of_Expenditures(models.Model):
    Expenditure_owner = models.CharField(default="None",max_length=50)
    Expenditure_Type = models.CharField(default="Miscellaneous",max_length=50)
    Expenditure_Type_Description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Expenditure_Type

class Expenditure(models.Model):
    exp_owner= models.CharField(default='None',max_length=50)
    exp_date = models.DateTimeField("Expenditure_Date")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="MYR",editable=True)
    exp_pocket = models.ForeignKey(Pockets, null=True, blank=True)
    exp_type = models.ForeignKey(Types_of_Expenditures)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('exp_date', 'description',)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

For above 2 models i am using below 2 forms :

```
class Types_of_Expenditures_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Types_of_Expenditures

class ExpenditureDeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExpenditureDeleteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['exp_pocket'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
        self.fields['exp_type'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
        self.fields['amount'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
        for f in self.fields:
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs['readonly'] = "readonly"
    class Meta:
        model = Expenditure
        exclude = ['exp_owner','currency']
        fields = ['exp_date', 'description', 'exp_type', 'amount','exp_pocket']
```

In my view i call it like this :

```
ExpDeleteFormSet = modelformset_factory(Expenditure,extra=0,
            can_delete=True,fields = ['exp_date', 'description', 'exp_type', 'amount','exp_pocket'],form=ExpenditureDeleteForm)
formset = ExpDeleteFormSet(queryset=Expenditure.objects.filter(exp_owner=str(request.user)))
return render_to_response('expenditure.html', {'formset':formset}, context)
```

Now the formset which is rendered is as below image :

**Problem/Question :**
As you can see in the image the Type is numbered as 1 or 2 . This 1 have corresponding value as Miscellaneous in Types_of_Expenditure and 2 have something else and so on . 
Is is possible to show type as corresponding value from Types_of_Expenditure ?

I have tried various things like using a Baseformset tried using a queryset but not able to find out how to do it ?

[image]

**What tried**

1. Using an inlineformset_factory as below but doing so dosent render anything in the template :

   ```
   ExpDeleteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Types_of_Expenditures, 
                                        Expenditure, fk_name="exp_type",
                                        fields = ['exp_date', 'description', 'exp_type', 'amount','exp_pocket'],
                                        can_delete=True,form=ExpenditureDeleteForm)
   ```

**Alternative which works well:** 
An Alternative which i have now used is to make Expenditure_Type itself as primary key , however i sill look for the answer of original question :

```
Expenditure_Type = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50)
```